# Airflow - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'

Tags: python, kubernetes, pip, airflow

I installed Python, Docker on my machine and am trying to import the
`from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator` but when I connect the docker, I get the message that the module does not exist. I have already done the `pip install apache-airflow[kubernetes]` and I still have the same error. Is there a specific machine location that I should check if the library is actually installed? What can I do to solve this?

[image]

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
import logging
import os
from airflow.utils.helpers import parse_template_string

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime.utcnow(),
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG(
    'kubernetes_sample', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=10))


start = DummyOperator(task_id='run_this_first', dag=dag)

passing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                          image="Python:3.6",
                          cmds=["Python","-c"],
                          arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="passing-test",
                          task_id="passing-task",
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag
                          )

failing = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace='default',
                          image="ubuntu:1604",
                          cmds=["Python","-c"],
                          arguments=["print('hello world')"],
                          labels={"foo": "bar"},
                          name="fail",
                          task_id="failing-task",
                          get_logs=True,
                          dag=dag
                          )

passing.set_upstream(start)
failing.set_upstream(start)
```

> webserver_1  | Traceback (most recent call last): webserver_1  |
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/models.py", line
>   377, in process_file webserver_1  |     m = imp.load_source(mod_name,
>   filepath) webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/imp.py",
>   line 172, in load_source webserver_1  |     module = _load(spec)
>   webserver_1  |   File "", line 684, in
>   _load webserver_1  |   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked webserver_1  |   File "", line 678, in exec_module webserver_1 
>   |   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed webserver_1  |   File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/example_airflow.py", line 3, in 
>   webserver_1  |     from
>   airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import
>   KubernetesPodOperator webserver_1  |   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py",
>   line 21, in  webserver_1  |     from
>   airflow.contrib.kubernetes import kube_client, pod_generator,
>   pod_launcher webserver_1  |   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/contrib/kubernetes/pod_launcher.py",
>   line 25, in  webserver_1  |     from kubernetes import watch,
>   client webserver_1  | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'kubernetes'

Comment: Try: `pip install airflow['kubernetes']`

Comment: @FelipeFB - did u resolve?

Comment: I just restart like @Kalil posted!

Comment: i got same error upgrading from 1.10.3 to 1.10.4 but that pip suggestion does not fix it :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run the following

```
pip install apache-airflow[kubernetes]
```

Restart Airflow webserver and scheduler after that.

Comment: i got same error upgrading from 1.10.3 to 1.10.4 but that pip suggestion does not fix it :(

Answer (score 3):

It tries to import module named kubernetes. Try that:

```
pip install kubernetes
```

Comment: I import this too... but nothing changed!

Answer (score 1):

try any of these imports. one of these got deprecated, so you might have a version that is no longer supported.

```
    #from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator
    from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
```

Comment: The second seems import one on my airflow version

`Broken DAG: [/airflow-dags/dags/dbt.py] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/airflow-dags/dags/dbt.py", line 3, in <module>
    from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator.py", line 25, in <module>
    from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have both `kubernetes` and `apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes` installed, then there's a chance you are running into this error to another `kubernetes.py` local file that exists somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH`.

If this is the case, then simply renaming that file should do the trick.